# Cordova file data directory aways change on iOS application update

Tags: ios, cordova

I need to download files, and store then in the dataDirectory. But When i start an application then i print:

console.log(cordova.file.dataDirectory);

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C5990CAA-439A-446E-A0B2-1212D3DC1072/Library/NoCloud/

When i build the application again, and prints the same console.log i got

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/40C1C96E-E4EF-4F20-82C0-D13AA0385202/Library/NoCloud/

Comment: what is wrong with that?

Comment: I save the complete path in localStorage, then i cant find the file.

Comment: Dont save whole path. Just save path further to `cordova.file.dataDirectory`. And when you need that file, just add `cordova.file.dataDirectory` as base path to that file.

Answer (score 1):

cordova.file.dataDirectory - Are a Persistent and private data storage within the application's sandbox using internal memory.

On each build  on iOS the dataDirectory will be changed, but the files is "moved to new" folder. I dont found any documentation with tecnichal info.

To resolve you need save only de path after dataDirectory, for example 
Your file will be safe in 
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/40C1C96E-E4EF-4F20-82C0-D13AA0385202/Library/NoCloud/**user/files/image.png**

You need save only **user/files/image.png**

To execute any operation with the file, copy, move, show you will use the  cordova.file.dataDirectory + **user/files/image.png**

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem using Capacitor, I had to do this to be able to see my pictures again after an update

```
photo.webviewPath = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(this.file.dataDirectory + photo.fileName).replace('Library/NoCloud', 'Documents');
```